# python3: logging.basicConfig sends everything to stderr?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following dead simple code:

```
import logging
import requests

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
res = requests.get('https://www.stackoverflow.com')
```

Being run like `python ./test.py  > foo.txt` sends everything to stderr. Why is this not going to stdout?

Comment: `>` only redirect stdout, `2>` redirect stderr and `&>` both output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`logging.basicConfig` uses `StreamHandler` when no `handler`/`filename`/`stream` parameter is given, and `StreamHandler` defaults to the STDERR stream:

```
class StreamHandler(Handler):

    def __init__(self, stream=None):
        """
        Initialize the handler.

        If stream is not specified, sys.stderr is used.
        """
        Handler.__init__(self)
        if stream is None:
            stream = sys.stderr  # <- Here
        self.stream = stream
```

To use the STDOUT, pass `sys.stdout` as `stream`:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, stream=sys.stdout)
```

---

Now, as you have currently, you can capture the STDERR from shell like:

```
python ./test.py  2> foo.txt
```

So redirecting the file descriptor 2 (which is STDERR) will do.

STDOUT is file descriptor 1 and when you do bare redirection `>`, `1>` is assumed.

If for some reason you want to use different files for redirecting two streams, you can do:

```
python ./test.py  >stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt
```

---

If you want to redirect both to the same file:

```
python ./test.py  >all.txt 2>&1  # POSIX
```

or

```
python ./test.py  &>all.txt  # `bash`-ism (works in other advanced shells as well)
```

Comment: That makes sense, I'll have to filter error+ for stderr if I want to maintain both streams. I thought there might be a quick way to establish error+ to stderr, anything else to stdout.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `logging.StreamHandler()` to your root handler and configure it to use `stdout`

```
import logging
import requests
import sys

root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
root.addHandler(handler)
res = requests.get('https://www.stackoverflow.com')
```